# My sudoer can not login using GUI

Tags: 14.04, login, sudo, desktop-environments, gdm

I only have one sudoer and it can login into the terminal or through GUI terminal. But I can not use it to log into the GDM login screen. 
Any possible causes?

Comment: Switch to tty1 and login, then post the output of `sudo startx -- :1`

Comment: Take a look at a file for that user in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` , for instance for me it would be `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` and make sure that his account isn't set to be system account, ie there should be a line saying SystemAccount=false. Another possibility is check if `.Xauthority` file in that user's home folder is not owned by root. It should be owned by the user and the user's group.